# Pull out content between two strings including strings

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do the following in python.

I have a file with the following content...

```
<VirtualHost>
  ServerName blah.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/blah.com
</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost>
  ServerName blah2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/blah2.com
</Virtualhost>

... etc
```

I want to take each of these virtual host containers and place them in a separate file(or variable and I can work from there)...

I have been able to take the data in between the strings but not including them.  So the output would be ...

```
<VirtualHost>
  ServerName blah2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/blah2.com
</Virtualhost>

...iterated through each container and not...
ServerName blah2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/blah2.com
```

Please let me know if this is something that can easily be done.  Thanks!

Comment: Try `http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html`

Comment: What is your code for extracting the data between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A findall regex might work:

```
import re

d = """
<VirtualHost>
  ServerName blah.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/blah.com
</Virtualhost>
<VirtualHost>
  ServerName blah2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/blah2.com
</Virtualhost>
"""

matches = re.findall(r'<VirtualHost>(.*?)</Virtualhost>', d, re.I|re.DOTALL)

#['\n  ServerName blah.com\n  DocumentRoot /var/www/blah.com\n',
# '\n  ServerName blah2.com\n  DocumentRoot /var/www/blah2.com\n']
```

Or to include the `<VirtualHost>` parts:

```
matches = re.findall(r'<VirtualHost>.*?</Virtualhost>', d, re.I|re.DOTALL)

#['<VirtualHost>\n  ServerName blah.com\n  DocumentRoot /var/www/blah.com\n</Virtualhost>',
# '<VirtualHost>\n  ServerName blah2.com\n  DocumentRoot /var/www/blah2.com\n</Virtualhost>']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input data is in XML, you can use [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) (as suggested by @Aesthete), or [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
import xml.dom.minidom as MD
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

input = """
<Document>
    <VirtualHost>
        ServerName blah.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/blah.com
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost>
        ServerName blah2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/blah2.com
    </VirtualHost>
</Document>"""

domDoc = MD.parseString(input)
etreeDoc = ET.fromstring(input)

# list for Python 3.x
miniDomOutput = list(map(lambda f: f.toxml(), domDoc.getElementsByTagName('VirtualHost')))
elementTreeOutput = list(map(lambda f: ET.tostring(f), etreeDoc.findall('VirtualHost')))

print(miniDomOutput)
print(elementTreeOutput)
```

Outputs:

```
#['<VirtualHost>\n        ServerName blah.com\n        DocumentRoot /var/www/blah.com\n    </VirtualHost>', '<VirtualHost>\n        ServerName blah2.com\n        DocumentRoot /var/www/blah2.com\n    </VirtualHost>']
#[b'<VirtualHost>\n        ServerName blah.com\n        DocumentRoot /var/www/blah.com\n    </VirtualHost>\n    ', b'<VirtualHost>\n        ServerName blah2.com\n        DocumentRoot /var/www/blah2.com\n    </VirtualHost>\n']
```